# access referenced projects at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a rather strange project where I need to check the assemblies of the projects included as references in my project to see if they contain a certain Type. As far as I can tell the only way to see which projects are in my solution is to parse the solution file - which I can't do at runtime since I don't have it.

Does anyone know a way to see, at runtime, which assemblies are in the project file?

Comment: I believe your looking for this previous answer here on SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241961/how-to-get-all-types-in-a-referenced-assembly

Comment: am I right, you want to know at some moment of time in runtime what assemblies are currently loaded?

Answer (score 1):

To check the referenced assemblies in your project assembly at runtime, you need to use Reflection.`this.GetType().Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`

Comment: Thanks, but those are only for assemblies that the executing assembly currently references (i.e. you have created an instance of a type defined in the reference). So that does not fit with what I need.

Comment: U r definitely writing code somewhere in your project to find out the assemblies. that somewhere might be static class and in that case u can change "this" to typeof(MyStaticClass) then this solution will fit your requirement.

Comment: Zafar is right, this will work if you change the `this` variable. I use code similar to this to manage plugin versions for one of my applications.