# How to get all types into a reference interop assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a couple interop assemblies which i need to get all types in them.
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241961/how-to-get-all-types-in-a-referenced-assembly) question and it does not work and doesn't apply to my case.
All these referenced assembly are used in my application directly but are not showing anywhere.

What i have tried and with the results i get is the following. Note that i simply tried with a single random class i have laying around and it does do same for all the other interop library i have in the project.

```
// Doesn't contain the assembly SldWorks.
var allAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

// {MyApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
// this is wrong
var assemblyOfClassInDLL = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Component2));

// {MyApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
// this is wrong
var assemblyOfClassInDLL2 = typeof(Component2).Assembly;

// SldWorks.Component2, MyApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// this is very wrong
var assemblyNameOfClassInDLL = typeof(Component2).AssemblyQualifiedName;

// Doesn't contain the assembly SldWorks.
var referencedAssemblies = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

try
{
    var testLoad = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyNameOfClassInDLL);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Could not load file or assembly 'SldWorks.Component2\, MyApp\, Version\=0.0.0.0\,
    // Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=null' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase
    // was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
}
```

Note above that `Component2` is a class within the assembly `SldWorks` which is an interop dll. Although the only line that seems to find it is `typeof(Component2).AssemblyQualifiedName` which return it wrong as it thinks it's in `MyApp`. Then you see in the `Try...Catch` that i am tryin to load that same assembly i just receive from the code and it crashes. Why C# return an assembly name that definitively do not exist ?

It msut be possible as i can in visual studio browse everything within the `Object Browser` window. So if the solution is to use the same code the `Object Browser` window does it's not an issue and performance either. This code save literally about 2 or 3 days work every time it's used instead of writing manually every class in a DLL in the code and update every time the companies release automatic updates.

I only have 2 requirements :

1 -  I ONLY get to receive an object that i need to find it's type and assembly it come from and return all the types in the same assembly

2 - My app is a dynamically loaded addin so it is NOT an executable

Comment: This can only work as intended when you set the "Embed Interop Types" property on the COM reference to False.  Do beware the consequences.

Comment: @HansPassant I already tried that and i cannot do that. It gives ~180,000 errors so i am out of luck